# The use of OF and ON in advertisement

Tags: prepositions

Please this statement, "Order for a plate OF any kind or Order for a plate ON any kind", which is correct?

Comment: More context needed.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of them is quite right. I think you probably want *of*, but I'm not sure what you are trying to say. If you can put a bit more context in your question, that might help.